# npx mrm lint-staged erroring out with 'Preset "default" not found."

Tags: prettier, npx, lint-staged

Example of the issue:

```
❯ npx mrm lint-staged
npx: installed 298 in 9.141s

Preset “default” not found.

We’ve tried to load “mrm-preset-default” and “default” npm packages.
```

Can't run this command and I don't know why!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is within `mrm` which is currently in version 3 that seems to be incompatible with lint-staged, to fix this you got to specify mrm version 2 by running `npx mrm@2 lint-staged`

Comment: Nice. That worked with `npx mrm@2 gitignore` as well.